# How to find energy of the signal $S_1(t) = \sqrt{t}$ where $t \in [-1,1]$

Tags: continuous-signals, signal-energy

What is the energy of the signal $S_1\left( t\right) = \sqrt{t}$ for $ t \in{[-1,1]}$ and $S_1(t) = 0$ otherwise. As all of we of us know, the energy of this signal should be finite.

However this signal seems to be a complex signal in the range of the $t \in {[-1,0)}$.

So how to evaluate the energy of the signal? When I have tried to evaluate the signal energy it seems that energy boils down to zero as the square of that function is  odd signal.

How we can proceed in this problem?

Comment: For a complex function $x(t)$, the energy is the integral of $x(t)x^*(t)$.

Comment: @MBaz That's an answer, not a comment!

Comment: I don't think this is a proper function. What would be its value for $ t = -1 $? Is it $ i $ or $ -i $?

Comment: Question is proper @Royi The thing is that when I am calculating orthonormal signal I have to divide the energy but here I got energy of the signal is zero thatswy asked

Comment: Function must have a single value at each input. The `sqrt()` operator doesn't obey this on negative values. You may define its value to be the upper plane but it has to be well defined.

Comment: Writing $S(t) = j\sqrt{|t|}$ when $t \in  [-1,0)$ and noting that, as @MBaz pointed out, that the energy is the integral of $S(t)S^*(t)$ (where $S^*(t) = -j\sqrt{|t|}$ when $t \in  [-1,0)$, we get $$E = \int_{-1}^1 S(t)S^*(t) \,\mathrm dt = \int_{-1}^0 |t| \, \mathrm dt + \int_0^1 t  \, \mathrm dt  \neq 0.$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate That's an answer, not a comment, as well! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This one is almost  too easy for a hint.

The energy is

$$E = \int_{t = -\infty}^{\infty} S_1^2(t) dt $$

Now if $S_1(t) = \sqrt{t}$, what is $S_1^2(t)$ ?

Comment: Why does $E$ equal the integral of $S_1^2(t)$ instead of the integral of $S_1(t)AS_1^*(t)$??

Comment: I think @DilipSarwate is correct, Hil.  (But I would set $A=1$.) $$ E_S \triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \big|S(t)\big|^2  \ \mathrm{d}t $$ The integrand is always non-negative, Hilmar.  But for negative $t$, how does that come out in your expression, Hil?